# How to calculates Iz, the moment of inertia about the z-axis?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

This is the exercise im struggling with:

The surface density of a thin rectangle varies as: 
$\sigma(x,y)= 11.0$ kg/m$^2$ $+ 5.00 $ kg/m$^4 (x^2+y^2)$ 
The rectangle has a length $L = 0.900$ m and a width $W = 0.900$ m. Calculate $I_z$, the moment of inertia about the $z$-axis.

[Depiction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT0Nq.gif)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's some guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Use the integral for the moment of inerzia around the $z$ axis:

$$I_z = \int \ell^2 dm$$

Where $dm$ is the mass element and $\ell$ is the distance from the axis.

In your case you have a rectangle (which is actually a square, since width and length are equal). The distance is then half the diagonal:

$$\ell^2 = d^2 = \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{4}$$

$$dm = \sigma dS$$

Where $\sigma$ is your surface density and $dS = dx dy$ is the area element. Hence the integral becomes

$$\int_0^{0.9} dx \int_0^{0.9} dy \frac{x^2 + y^2}{4} (11.0 + 5(x^2 + y^2)) dx dy$$

The integral is pretty trivial, do the maths and you will get

$$\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{11}{3}x^3 + \frac{11}{3}y^3 + x^5 + y^5 + \frac{2}{9}x^3y^3\right)$$

To be calculated at $x = y = 0.9$.

Comment: Why is $\ell^2 = (x^2+y^2)/4$? I disagree with the division by 4 here.

Comment: @NickPavlov I used $\ell^2$ as the distance from the center, that is half the diagonal, hence $(x/2)^2 + (y/2)^2$. Is that wrong?

Comment: Why from the center? (OP didn't specify that, so I would have assumed the actual z-axis; while it is customary to express inertia of symmetric objects around axes through the center, here "center" is ill-defined; if anything, center of mass might make sense, but that is not the geometric center). And anyway, if from the center, it should be $(x - L/2)^2 + (y - W/2)^2$; after all, the integral is from $0$ to $L$ and $0$ to $W$, so center is $(L/2, W/2)$. Is it possible you are confusing the (variable) coordinates $x,y$ with the (fixed) lengths $L,W$? Diagonals  have nothing to do with it.